# FileNotFoundException:file:xxx\.m2\repository\xxxx\xxx\xxx.jar!\filename, when running main from IDEA

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea

I have a project that build from eclplse, and a java class that main method runs well but fail to run when I try to run it from IDEA.

The main method will initially try to load a properties file from classbath by below code from **ANOTHER** dependency project(wemq-client):

```
 filePath = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fileName).getPath();
 ....//something else

 prop = new Properties();
 prop.load(new FileInputStream(new File(filePath)));
```

But when I run in InteliJ, I have following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at .....
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\C:\Users\jaskeylin\.m2\repository\cn\webank\wemq\wemq-client\0.1.3\wemq-client-0.1.3.jar!\wemq-client.properties (文件名、目录名或卷标语法不正确。)
```

which `文件名、目录名或卷标语法不正确。` means file name or dictionary name syntax not correct.

We can see from the error statck that it tries to find this file from maven repo's package jar file. Why is that? How can I fix it.

PS: If you are suggesting I modify the code, please also explain why this works from eclipse, since this works quite fine from my teamates, there is only me who hopes to use IDEA

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the file name in the error message, you're trying to open file `wemq-client.properties` inside file `wemq-client-0.1.3.jar` using a `FileInputStream`. You cannot do that. You can only open real files on the file system, not files inside archives.

In short, **NEVER EVER** do `getResource(...).getPath()`. There is a reason the [`getResource(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) method returns a `URL`, and not a `File`. Because the resource may not *be* a file.

Instead, use the [`getResourceAsStream(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29), and give that `InputStream` directly to the [`load(InputStream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.InputStream%29) method.

As always, remember to close your resources, preferably using try-with-resources.

```
prop = new Properties();
try (InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName)) {
    prop.load(inputStream);
}
```

Or use any alternate version of `getResourceAsStream()` as suggested in [answer by @SanjitKumarMishra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37559913/5221149).

You *can* use the `getResource(String)` method if you want, but you must then open the stream using the [`URL.openStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream%28%29) method.

```
URL fileUrl = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fileName);
....//something else

prop = new Properties();
try (InputStream inputStream = fileUrl.openStream()) {
    prop.load(inputStream);
}
```

The reason it works inside Eclipse, is that you're running directly off files on the file system, however when you package and deploy your code, it's packaged inside jar files, and you get the error you see.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot using FileInputStream to read files in jar, you can using `someclass.class.getResourceAsStream(name)` to read the file

just

```
 prop = new Properties();
 prop.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName));
```

Comment: That will cause a resource-leak.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading the class from an Application Server, so your should use **`Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName)`** instead of `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName)`. `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream()` will also work.

Read [this article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2003-08/01-qa-0808-property.html) for more detailed information about that particular problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can use HTTPSERVLETREQUEST to get file path.

**HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();**

**String filePath = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+filename;**

Comment: File exists inside a jar file, i.e. on the classpath. It is not a Servlet resource.

Comment: okay. you can add this jar file in Deployment assembly separately and try once again